# How to use frame support FindAuthor trait in a custom pallet

Tags: pallet, authorship

I'm trying to use `frame_support::traits::FindAuthor` in my pallet for a custom logic.

I imported the traits and I tried to loose coupling it.

this is my config:

```rust
#[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;

        type FindAuthor: FindAuthor<Self::AccountId>;
    }
```

So now I want to use `find_author()` function of this trait

```rust
let author = T::FindAuthor::find_author(digests???);
```

but I'm stuck with the digests param, I don't understand what "digests" means and how to pass it in order to get the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are pre-runtime digests, which as [the documentation](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/generic/enum.DigestItem.html#variant.PreRuntime) says are

> messages from the consensus engine to the runtime, although the consensus engine can (and should) read them itself to avoid code and state duplication. It is erroneous for a runtime to produce these, but this is not (yet) checked.

You can obtain digests for the current block like this:

```rust
let block_digest = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::digest();
let digests = block_digest.logs.iter().filter_map(|d| d.as_pre_runtime());
let author = T::FindAuthor::find_author(digests);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine!